# Cake php join query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have write this join query in cake php 1.3.

```
$supportbooks=$this->Supportbook->find('all',array('joins'=>array(
                              array(
                               'table'=>'supportbookstatuses',
                               'alias'=>'supportstatus',
                               'conditions' =>array('supportstatus.unique_id=Supportbook.`unique_key`')
                              )
                            )),array('conditions'=>array('Supportbook.user_id'=>$user_id)));
```

This return the following query:

```
SELECT `Supportbook`.`id`, `Supportbook`.`category`, `Supportbook`.`user_id`, `Supportbook`.`email`, `Supportbook`.`subject`, `Supportbook`.`message`, `Supportbook`.`reply`, `Supportbook`.`unique_key`, `Supportbook`.`replied` FROM `fl_supportbooks` AS `Supportbook` JOIN `fl_supportbookstatuses` AS `supportstatus` ON (`supportstatus`.`unique_id`=`Supportbook`.`unique_key`) WHERE 1 = 1
```

The where clause is not working. There should be a where clause : WHERE Supportbook.user_id=21 
How will I add the where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a parentesis error. It should be:

```
$supportbooks=$this->Supportbook->find('all',array('joins'=>array(
                              array(
                               'table'=>'supportbookstatuses',
                               'alias'=>'supportstatus',
                               'conditions' =>array('supportstatus.unique_id=Supportbook.`unique_key`')
                              )
                            ),'conditions'=>array('Supportbook.user_id'=>$user_id)));
```

Comment: Sorry I dont get the point but I copy and paste the code in my page its getting the same problem. Can you point out the problem please.

Comment: I've edited my answer. The index 'conditions' must be at the same level as 'joins'